# Confidence value of each Bounding Box

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, svm, bounding-box, conv-neural-network

I am currently working on Image classification given an image with neural network. I have successfully created the bounding boxes over the image and for each bounding box I have applied classification algorithm(W^X+B where W, B are weights and biases already learned from training data) to get a value for each of 20 classes.

For one bounding box the value I got for 20 classes :

```
 221.140961  71.6502609  185.005554 14.2860174   177.44928   -20.842535
-16.2324142 -105.940437 -397.505829 132.100311  -12.3567591  262.162872 
-243.444672 -198.083984 19.3514423  1.94239163  -75.0622787 -93.7277069 
-181.89653   260.002625
```

the **class predicted is class 11** (index of class starting from 0) which has max value 262.162872. I have also come across some papers where I could find the confidence value for each bounding box is usually calculated and its value ranges from 0 to 1.

**How to get this confidence value for each bounding box ?** Is it just the probability of class 11 with respect to all other classes? 
In this data how do I get it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert the output of a neural network to probabilities, softmax is usually used:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function

This ensures that very small values become near-zero probabilities and very large values become near-one probabilities.  The ends of the range are relatively insensitive to *how large* the value is, the middle of the range is much more sensitive.  It also ensures all the probabilities add up to 1.  This is appropriate to multiclass classification (where the classes are disjoint).

Note that an activation function (such as ReLU) is usually not applied before softmax.  So a typical network is convolution -> ReLU -> ... -> convolution -> ReLU -> convolution -> softmax.

P.S. Does your neural network really have one layer as you described?  This doesn't usually produce good results.

Comment: I have used 2 convolution-pooling layer (with ReLU) and then 1 fully connected layer followed by softmax layer just like  LeNet. But the softmax output I am getting is 1 for a particular class and 0 for most of the other classes with some negligible values (1e-30) for rest. That is why I thought that the confidence value might be something else. The class where softmax output = 1 is not correct class. So I thought there is some problem with this model.

Comment: @Kapes: Softmax is what you want for multiclass, so at least that part is correct.  If you are getting many results with very high (close to 1) confidence which is wrong, then your network is overfitted.  Try using more training data or using data augmentation on your existing data.

Comment: I am using pascal voc 2012 training dataset from which I am using 10000 as training and rest as validation set. Yes you are right I will have to use data augmentation as the training data is low and probably will have to train for some more epochs. Currently I am training for around 200 epochs. Also I have thought of using some dropout. At least now I know I am going in the right direction.